# Browse and Stream

Tags: meaning

I know that browse means to go through websites in Internet and stream is like a live stream or something like that.

I was answering something but this question stopped me, I am confused which one is correct.

- When you watch a video on the internet you .. (browse it - evolve it - stream it)

Comment: You browse to find it, you steam to watch it.

Answer (score 0):

If you watch a video on a site such as YouTube or Vimeo, then you stream it.  The data is being sent to your computer as you are watching it.

Comment: Whoever downvoted Simon's Answer, could you justify that, please?